# Separate splitting on whitespace when not told to

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a variable in my data that is separted by |#|, the data is a mix of alpha numeric and contains white space throughout.

Using separate within TidyR I have specicied my sep as "|#|", but when the process runs it splits the variable by white space as well as with the specified separator.

How do I force this command to ignore white space and only split based on what I have specified?

My code is as below:

```
library(tidyr)
Tasks2 <- Tasks2 %>%
  mutate(Task_Filter = paste(Task_Type_ID)) %>%
  separate('Task_Filter', paste("Task_Filter", 1:4, sep= "|#|"), extra = "drop")
```

An example of a value being split would be

> 4 |#| NB quote referred |#| 0000 0000 |#| 20/01/2021 |#| Connect
> System

I chose |#| because that is what is present in the source data, all entries have the same format. I expect the 4 new variables to be, from this example, 4,
NB quote referred,
0000 0000,
20/01/2021

But what I am getting is:
4
NB
Quote
Referred

Comment: You can use `sep= "\\|#\\|"`. As `|` is a special character in regex and needs to be escaped to match literally.

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah, I've just tried that but the output remains the same, still splitting the white space.

Comment: Can you provide your data using `dput` ? Edit your post to include the output of `dput(head(Tasks2, 10))`

Comment: @RonakShah unfortunately not as sensitive corporate data. The variable in question is structured as chr [1:59042]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `separate` by taking not only the pipes but also the whitespaces into the pattern:

```
library(tidyr)
separate(df, col = "x", into = paste("Task_Filter", 1:5), sep = "\\s\\|#\\|\\s")
  Task_Filter 1     Task_Filter 2 Task_Filter 3 Task_Filter 4  Task_Filter 5
1             4 NB quote referred     0000 0000    20/01/2021 Connect System
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
          x = "4 |#| NB quote referred |#| 0000 0000 |#| 20/01/2021 |#| Connect System")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution. I am not sure if this is wanted. Please tell me.
I case the number of columns to seperate in is not known `cSplit` is quite handy.

```
library(splitstackshape)

df1 <- df %>% 
  cSplit('x', '|#|') %>% 
  select(everything()[c(TRUE, FALSE)])
```

Output:

```
   x_1               x_3       x_5        x_7            x_9
1:   4 NB quote referred 0000 0000 20/01/2021 Connect System
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint @TarJae, always good to have alternatives!